# Does NSUserDefaults persist after app transfer?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

For apps that were transferred between one dev account to another dev account (different teams and thus will have different bundle id prefixes), once an update has been released from the new dev account, do values stored in `NSUserDefaults` persist or does the whole thing get cleared?

Comment: Just install the app into your device, if it become 2nd app, the `NSUserDefault` will not be there for the new app, because it's follow with the app itself

Comment: NSUserDefaults persists between app updates, so if this was a regular update it shouldnt be a problem. The issue is that you can not "test" any dev build or ad-hoc builds on devices that have the previous "pre-transfer" version of the app. This is a known issue and is documented by apple, however they don't mention anything about NUSerDefaults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually `YES` - I tested this with two live apps that were transferred from one itunes connect account to another (with different Team IDs) and that just `NSUserDefaults` to store and load user data/settings. As I suspected, the reason this does indeed work is because `NSUserDefaults` do not rely on the bundle identifier's prefix to figure out which container to use.

TLDR:

**YES**

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO and here is the reason.

Data will persist in NSUserDefaults for the entire lifetime of the app,

if you are installing a app with another bundle id [New Bundle ID] so it will count as a another app so that will not hold any old data which is in old app [old bundle ID] .

Comment: yes, but the bundle id is essentially the same. The prefix (which his hidden from bundle id has been changed), and according to NSUserDefaults docs, the prefix is not included when deciding apps NSUserDefault "container"...so have you actually tested this?